# Google Plus Interactive Posts not displayed on any stream (Client side API)

Tags: google-plus

As the title denotes, looking for insight on reasons why an **Interactive Post** doesn't show up on any stream (user sharing the post, and to whomever the user is sharing it with).

### Brief

- Implement client side api of G+ interactive posts
- This *seems* successful

  - application auth is requested and if granted is displayed in user's "[applications list](https://plus.google.com/apps)"
  - intended content, prefill text, etc. are all displayed when the trigger to initiate the share is invoked
  - no error indicators (that I know of) are displayed when the "Share" button is clicked by the user (the act of actually posting the share).
  - it is **visible** in some way *only* to Google - explained below

### Findings

- It seems Google is blocking the post because even though the share isn't posted on any stream (origin nor target), I received a warning about violating Google policies as displayed below, indicating that the (http) post was sent/submitted...
  [image: screen shot of warning display]
- further inspection of network activity also displays what *looks like* (a guess on my part) a *spam score* (of 8), somehow *already* pre-determined (another guess on my part):
  `https://apis.google.com/u/0/_/sharebox/post/?spam=8&hl=en&ozv=...`

### Questions

- Primary question is why would interactive posts not appear on stream? Any debugging tool out there?
- **IF** my guess on spam blocking is accurate, then why would such be the case? For *interactive posts* (which somehow inherently is a case of some user "promoting" something in the first place) - eg: with a "BUY" `calltoactionlabel`?
- **IF** my other guess on the content being "pre-tagged" as spam, how/why would that occur. I didn't include it above, but it is a "product page" - the idea of it, which isn't new nor revolutionary, is to give the opportunity for a user to "share" an item he/she just purchased, say in a normal checkout flow?
- It's my  *assumption* that implementation was done correctly, no errors reported, etc. - or perhaps it wasn't? Though it seems unlikely, it's "grasping at straws" time..

Further testing/debugging seems unwise given the warning of policy violation - and yes, I've stopped further dev on this to prevent harming my accounts (one personal, one work, both used above for testing this API).

Thanks for any assistance/input.

Note: I've posted this on [G+ community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/113527920160449995981) (no luck so far) so once this is resolved I'll share the answer there too (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are posting the Interactive post from `http://localhost` or from any private domain url. Google crawler can only allow interactive post from public domain.

As from their website -

**Important**: Interactive posts will not work when PhotoHunt is hosted at `http://localhost:8888` because the Google crawler can only access public URLs to get microdata about the content of the post. In the case of PhotoHunt for Java, you can deploy your app to appspot.com as a public Google App Engine app.

Comment: Hmm...could be. Though I distinctly remember testing for that (localhost issues) and moving the test page to a live box. I haven't done any further `G+ interactive posts` dev since the above :) I should get back on it and try. Thanks!

Comment: Will do as soon as I can confirm this - as stated, I'm pretty sure I've tried this already in the past (to no avail). Thanks again.